# Import module that contain relative path importing in Python

Tags: python, module, package, modulenotfounderror

I have a project tree as follow:

```
C:.
│   infer.py
│
└───models
    │   __init__.py
    │
    ├───cnn
    │       cnn.py
    │
    └───yolo
        │   yolo.py
        │
        └───model
                exp.py
                __init__.py
```

In models/yolo/yolo.py, I've import a module by relative path like this:

```
from model.exp import Hello2


def Hello3():
    Hello2()
    print("Hello 3")
```

And in infer.py:

```
from models.yolo.yolo import Hello3


Hello3()
```

So when I execute code in infer.py, It's turn out like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\hoang\OneDrive\Desktop\test_module_py\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 1, in <module>
    from models.yolo.yolo import Hello3
  File "c:\Users\hoang\OneDrive\Desktop\test_module_py\models\yolo\yolo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from model.exp import Hello2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'
```

SO how can i deal with this problem

Please help me! Thanks a lot

Comment: I believe you want `.model.exp` instead of `model.exp`

Comment: Yes that's help but in real project, the yolo folder contain so many files like yolo.py. So I have to change them all. Are there any solution ? @Dillon Davis

Comment: You could use a tool like `sed` if you're on linux or have git bash or cygwin installed.  `sed -i 's/from models\./from .models./' *`. Note this won't recurse. You'd need to use `find -name '*.py' -exec SED_COMMAND \;` in addition for that.